# Regexp for a string to contain only letters , numbers and space in Java

Tags: java, regex, string

Requirement: String should contain only letters , numbers and space.
             I have to pass a clean name to another API.

Implementation: Java

I came up with this for my requirement

```
public static String getCleanFilename(String filename) {
    if (filename == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return filename.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9 ]","");
}
```

This works well for few of my testcase , but want to know am I missing any boundary conditions, or any better way (in performance) to do it.

Comment: If you are **validating** a filename, you shouldn't be **modifying** it.

Comment: So what would you want to use for `"____"`.

Comment: This will almost certainly piss users off. Just detect the negative and let the user know what they can and can't enter.

Comment: Requirement is , I have to pass a clean name to another API. (so modifying is required)

Comment: may be use non-word pattern `\W` it contains underscore as well. see here http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Comment: Letters are `\pL` **NOT** `[A-Za-z]`.  Numbers are `\pN` **NOT** `[0-9]`.  And spaces in filenames are **EVIL**.

Comment: @tchrist: sat probably means English letters and numbers.

Comment: @Tim: *Coöperate*, *coëval*, *learnèd*, *archæology*, and *œnology* are all English words. So are a lot of others, like *self-satisfied* and *who’d*. And contrary to popular believe, so are *naïve*, *façade*, *résumé*, and *rôle*.

Comment: @tchrist Indeed, but ë, ' and - and are not considered English letters.

Comment: @tchrist I believe that OP is attempting to match a filename containing English letters, not English words. Whether that is appropriate in a Unicode world is a different question :)

Comment: @Tim: I believe that it is **not** appropriate in a Unicode world, because you cannot spell English correctly without more than `[a-z]`.  It is inappropriate to expect people to spell things incorrectly or to restrict which words they may use.

Comment: @Tim: The best way to match “English letters” in Java is probably to use `[\p{Latin}&&\pL]`, but that needs JDK7 to get the Latin script property; you can’t use the block property for this. That misses diacritics, but Java doesn’t support the basic Unicode Alphabetic property, which would pick those up; so would the basic Unicode Diacritic property. You could punt by saying `([\p{Latin}&&\pL]\pM*)+` for one or more such combos.

Comment: @tchrist: I completely agree, but believe that it is irrelevant in this case since OP is _not_ trying to match English text. He seems to want a nice filename.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you're direct question, `\t` fails your method and passes through as "space." Switch to `\s` (`[...\s]` and you're good.

At any rate, your design is probably flawed. Instead of arbitrarily dicking with user input, let the user know what you don't allow and make the correction manual.

**EDIT:**
If the filename doesn't matter, take the SHA-2 hash of the file name and use that. Guaranteed to meet your requirements.

Comment: I am picking the filename myself from another activity or event. But yeah thats true. I should notify user about what characters are allowed, if he tries to modifies the filename. Thank you.

Comment: I am using filename.replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9\\s]",""); now.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to comments: i don't think that performance is an issue in a scenario where user input is taken (and a filename shouldn't be that long...).

But concerning your question: you may reduce the number of replacements by adding an additional + in your regex:

`[^A-Za-z0-9 ]+`

Comment: Letters are not `[A-Za-z]`, and Numbers are not `[0-9]`.